# Python BeautifulSoup - Attributerror: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I get a traceback error (see below) when running this code. I am pretty new to this and can't simply get my head around why its not working

for row in tableStats.findAll('tr')[2:]:
Attributerror: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'findAll'

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request

    f = open('C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Projects\FFootball_DiamonMine\outfileESPN.txt','w')
    errorFile = open ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Projects\FFootball_DiamonMine\errorESPN.txt','w')

    x = 0
    while (x < 500):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?startIndex='+str(x)).read(), 'html.parser')
        tableStats = soup.find("table", ("class" "playerTableTable tableBody"))
        for row in tableStats.findAll('tr')[2:]:
            col = row.findAll('td')

            try:
                name = col[0].a.string.strip()
                f.write(name+'\n')

            except Exception as e:
                errorFile.write (str(x) + '*********' + str(e) + '********************' + str(col)  +'\n')
                pass

        x = x + 40

    f.close
    errorFile.close
```

Comment: The exception is pretty explicit. `'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'findAll'` means `tableStats = soup.find("table" ...)` returned `None`. If you copy-and-pasted your code directly, your error may lie in the comma missing inside your `("class" "playerTableTable tableBody")` tuple.